# how to displays the password that is loaded into the datatables in the <td> section

Tags: html

I want to show a password using table.

```
<th field="password" editor="password">Password</th>
```

I'm already change to `<th>Password</th>`

but on `<td>` still cannot show a password.

thanks for advance

Comment: Please describe more about your question and put some image to declare your problem.

Comment: please use input not <th>. example : <input type="password" name="password">

Answer (score 0):

As I understand, you want to load the password from somewhere and display it.

If you use Query, you can do something like this. First of all, give your th that should disply the password an id.

```
<th id="pwd">Password</th>
```

Second, after you loaded the password somewhere in your JavaScript, you can set the text of your th to the loaded password.

```
$("#pwd").text("secretPassword");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have this kind of code for the user to **submit** the password:

```
    <form action="/action_page.php">
    <input type="password" name="pwd"> 
    </form>
```

And you want to **retrieve** the input, use following PHP code to try, because you did not specified the language.

in `action_page.php`

```
<?php echo $_GET['pwd']; ?> // this will give you the input
```

And then show it in the table as you want.

Refer to https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp for table proper format

Because you did not provide the context, hope this will help.